# Change continuous to discrete axis and set axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some problems with the following code:

```
Vo2Max.Auswertung %>% 
group_by(group) %>% 
summarise(across(everything(), mean)) %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = "test", values_to = "mean") %>% 
mutate(test = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",test))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=test, y = mean, group = group, color = group)) + 
geom_line(aes(),size = 1.1) +
geom_point(aes(), size = 3)+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("lightskyblue", "royalblue"), name = "Legende") +                                                                                
ggtitle("Mittelwerte VO2 Max Vergleich nach Gruppen") +                                                                                                        
theme_bw() +                                                                                                                                                    
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +                                                                                                                  
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, angle = 90)) +                                                                                                     
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, hjust=1)) +                                                                                                         
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15)) +                                                                                                                 
scale_x_continuous(name = "Testzeitpunkt") +
scale_y_continuous(name = "Mittelwerte VO2 max") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This is the result

[image: This is the result]

I have to scale the x axes into 3 timepoints (t0, t1, t2).
The y axes has to have an other scale (from 40 to 45).

Can someone help me to find the mistaces?

Here are my datas:

```
> Vo2Max.Auswertung
# A tibble: 18 x 4
 group              `t0 VO2 max` `t1 VO2 max` `t2 VO2 max`
 <chr>                     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 Experimentalgruppe         47.6         47.9         48.7
 2 Kontrollgruppe             47.6         46.5         43.0
 3 Experimentalgruppe         47.6         48.7         48.7
 4 Kontrollgruppe             46.8         47.6         46.2
 5 Kontrollgruppe             44.6         46.2         47.9
 6 Experimentalgruppe         41.3         42.1         42.4
 7 Kontrollgruppe             38           40.7         38.6
 8 Experimentalgruppe         43.5         44.6         42.7
 9 Experimentalgruppe         41.9         43.2         43.8
10 Kontrollgruppe             45.1         47.9         49.2
11 Experimentalgruppe         44.1         44.3         44.9
12 Kontrollgruppe             28.5         30.9         30.3
13 Kontrollgruppe             38.6         41.6         42.1
14 Kontrollgruppe             44.6         45.4         47.6
15 Kontrollgruppe             40.4         43.0         42.4
16 Experimentalgruppe         32.6         33.3         33.3
17 Experimentalgruppe         40.4         38.6         43.0
18 Kontrollgruppe             44.3         40.1         42.7
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. simply add `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(40, 45))` to your plot

Comment: and, even more important - try to avoid spaces in your column names. You're making your own life miserable

Comment: hey, nice, the  `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(40, 45))`  helped.
Do u have a tip fot the x axes?

Comment: `+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 3))` does not work, i tried
but i cleand up my code a little :-)

Comment: i think it has something to do with `ggplot(aes(x=test` my x axes scale is not correct

Comment: @Jugglerz What did you want for x-axis? 0, 1, and 2 (or t0, t1, and t2) for the time points? I think you may want something different for `gsub`...?

Comment: i want to have t0, t1 and t2 on the x axes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't get this with the x axis. Below a suggestion including some tips to improve your plotting.

Check mainly how I label title, x axis and y axis, and how I summarise the theme specs to one single call to theme

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), mean)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = "test", values_to = "mean") %>%

# the following is quite a change. I am using a factor instead of numeric
# Also I am using str_sub to extract the number
  mutate(test = as.factor(str_sub(test, 2, 2))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = test, y = mean, group = group, color = group)) +
  geom_line(aes(), size = 1.1) +
  geom_point(aes(), size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("lightskyblue", "royalblue"), name = "Legende") +
  labs(
    x = "Testzeitpunkt", y = "Mittelwerte VO2 max",
    title = "Mittelwerte VO2 Max Vergleich nach Gruppen"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, angle = 90),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 1),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
```

as per (now deleted) comments, you can simply extract the additional "t" by changing
`test =str_sub(test, 1, 2)`. because you're adding the character t, R will recognise it as a character vector and you don't need to factorise anymore

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**data**

```
# devtools::install_github("alistaire47/read.so")

foo <- read.so::read_so("group t0_VO2_max t1_VO2_max t2_VO2_max
<chr>                     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
  1 Experimentalgruppe         47.6         47.9         48.7
2 Kontrollgruppe             47.6         46.5         43.0
3 Experimentalgruppe         47.6         48.7         48.7
4 Kontrollgruppe             46.8         47.6         46.2
5 Kontrollgruppe             44.6         46.2         47.9
6 Experimentalgruppe         41.3         42.1         42.4
7 Kontrollgruppe             38           40.7         38.6
8 Experimentalgruppe         43.5         44.6         42.7
9 Experimentalgruppe         41.9         43.2         43.8
10 Kontrollgruppe             45.1         47.9         49.2
11 Experimentalgruppe         44.1         44.3         44.9
12 Kontrollgruppe             28.5         30.9         30.3
13 Kontrollgruppe             38.6         41.6         42.1
14 Kontrollgruppe             44.6         45.4         47.6
15 Kontrollgruppe             40.4         43.0         42.4
16 Experimentalgruppe         32.6         33.3         33.3
17 Experimentalgruppe         40.4         38.6         43.0
18 Kontrollgruppe             44.3         40.1         42.7")
```

Comment: its close, but not full correct :-) 
i need exacty `t0, t1 and t2` on the x axes

Comment: i guess it should be here somwhere `ggplot(aes(x = test, y = mean, group = group, color = group)`
maybe i have to add `name`or something like this

Comment: i tried to add a "t" here `mutate(test = as.factor(str_sub(test, 2, 2))) %>%" `but it dosen´t work

Comment: wow, nice thanks fot the help!!!
Its not as hard as it seams to be... also for a upcoming teacher for physical eduacation ;-)